# Vue data not updated in created()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to transform an API response into a more useful form for building two tables. When I add debugging outputs inside my function in `created()`, I can see the desired output, but examining the data after the fact, it seems to have not changed. I suspect that something weird is happening with `this`, but I can't seem to sort it out.

Here's what I have so far:

```
export default {
  name: 'component',
  data: function() {
      return {
        tableOne: [],
      }
  },
  computed: {
      ...mapState([
        'modal'
      ])
  },
  created() {
  api.get_appointments()
      .then(appointments => {
          for (var i = 0; i < appointments.length; i++) {            
              this.tableOne.push(
                  {
                      tech: appointments[i].tech_name,
                      date: appointments[i].scheduled_date
                  }
              )
          }
      });
  },
};
```

`api.get_appointments()` includes the following:

```
get_appointments() {
  return axios({
    method: "get",
    url: '/appointments'
  })
  .then(res => (res.data.data))
  .catch(error => {return error});
};
```

Comment: It because your output runs before complete ```api.get_appointments()``` function, so try to use async and await, let me answer it.

Comment: It's already answered so you can check that.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's doing a  request hit..the second console prints before the request is resolved. Try using async-await

```
async created() {
  await api.get_appointments()
      .then(appointments => {
          for (var i = 0; i < appointments.length; i++) {            
              this.tableOne.push(
                  {
                      tech: appointments[i].tech_name,
                      date: appointments[i].scheduled_date
                  }
              )
          }
          // console.log(this.tableOne);
      });
  // console.log(this.tableOne);
  },
```

Comment: To clarify, when this is all finished, the Vue data property this.tableOne is still [], even after I can confirm in that in the created function, this.tableOne is being updated properly. The comments are to illustrate the effect of scope, rather than timing. Any point after this function is complete and the Promise satisfied, this.tableOne is still []

Comment: I edited my example to remove the bit about output since trying to evaluate this.tableOne from ANY scope at ANY point after the the response has been confirmed received and accurate within the function still always yields [].

Comment: Did u try the above solution?

Comment: Created is a vue lifecycle hook. You can't make it async. Regardless, the point stands that there is no point after I have confirmed the response where the data item this.tableOne is properly updated in the outter scope, although it appears to be within the inner scope.